# Nautilus takes an awfully long time to launch for me on 15.04. Does anyone know why?

Tags: nautilus, 15.04

I'm running 15.04 and have found Nautilus to take about 10 minutes to launch following updates from about two weeks ago. When I look at `top` it appears that `Compiz` and `Xorg` are doing a lot while it is launching. Previously it would take just an instant to open.

When I observe this behaviour, I observe it for all of Nautilus, everything from desktop rendering to launching of the file browser.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what to do about it?

Comment: run the command `nautilus` from terminal. what is the output?

Comment: Well, with the most recent update the delay has gone away. I can't show you! This may remain a mystery.

Comment: Ok, the delay is back. Run from the terminal, Nautilus produces messages like ```GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed```, ```Could not register the application: Timeout was reached``` and ```GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed```. Then the launch halts. However, somehow it eventually manages to launch. Would you happen to know what's going on?

Comment: I had a similar problem. It was caused by me putting my home dir under mercurial and having the tortoisehg extension installed, resulting in stat'ing my entire home dir. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1522177